# What can affect google results in different locations?

Tags: seo, google

My website has very different SERP positions depending on the country. Especially low positions in developed countries such as the USA and UK. I've been trying to do something with it for 5 years. During this time, I have changed site content many times, optimized website speed, made a responsive design, but nothing helps. Website traffic has reached almost 1M visits/month, but that didn't change the results either. Here are the country stats for the "minesweeper" keyword:

- Germany - 3.4
- Austria - 3.6
- Switzerland - 4.8
- Japan - 4.7
- Thailand - 4.1
- Romania - 6.9
- Croatia - 6.4
- Taiwan - 4.5
- Indonesia - 7.3
- South Korea - 6.6
- ...
- United States - 10+
- United Kingdom - 10+
- Canada - 10+
- Australia - 10+

Why is this happening, and how can I fix this?

Comment: It makes sense that site srank differently by country. There are many factors in ranking pages and locality affects some of them.

Comment: I would interested to know if any of there's any consistency in any of the sites that rank higher than you.  For example, are there any sites that are higher than you in multiple countries?  Are the sites that rank higher than you, uniquely located in the specific country they rank well in?